# Сохранение строк, в разные файлы, с одинаковым текстом, между знаками

Tags: delphi, строки, файлы

Есть текстовый файл, в котором **(пример)** строк:

```
Text6№111>Text1
Text5№111>Text2
Text4№222>Text3
Text3№222>Text4
Text2№333>Text5
Text1№333>Text6
```

**Вопрос:** Как сохранить, все строки, по разным, текстовым файлам, где между символами **№** и **>** встречаются одинаковый (идентичный) текст.

В данном случае:

**В текстовый файл 1 сохранится (поскольку текст 111 между знаками № и > одинаковый):**

```
Text6№111>Text1
Text5№111>Text2
```

**В текстовый файл 2 сохранится (поскольку текст 222 между знаками № и > одинаковый):**

```
Text4№222>Text3
Text3№222>Text4
```

**В текстовый файл 3 сохранится (поскольку текст 333 между знаками № и > одинаковый):**

```
Text2№333>Text5
Text1№333>Text6
```

Возможно такое, вообще, сделать через функцию **Pos** ?

Comment: Да, это возможно сделать с помощью pos. Укажите версию делфи и я вам подскажу как(готового кода не будет, только компоненты, примеры и описание алгоритма).

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: Вот, зря расписывал как сделать примитивный ассоциативный массив =) у вас есть женерики, хоть это не совсем то, но в вашем случае можно использовать "словарь" (TDictonary)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Для меня задание сложновато но ничего не поделать - буду пробовать...

Comment: Что именно сложного? как разложить по разным листам - расписано в п4 ответа. как сохранить в п5. как загрузить - `TStringList.LoadFromFile('FileName')`.. (п3.) порядок действий - описан. осталось использовать минимум фантазии, и написать код(куски которого с некоторыми допущениями приведены)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Вот как раз и это минимум буду елозить. В любом случае благодарен за советы.

Comment: Допущения сделаны специально чтобы нельзя было скопировать куски воедино без понимания что происходит... 20 минут чтения примеров по использованным компонентам(или понимание минимума по делфи) и пример взлетит =) сайт то для помощи а не работы за автора =) общая идея выказана в первых строках ответа =)

Comment: Вам что то из ответа стало непонятно или вы расчитываете на готовый код? потому что я лично предлагаю закрыть вопрос как учебный =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, в данном случае на готовый код, я же в задании к конкурсу описал это. Поскольку мои варианты медленно работают и не обрабатывают файлы в 800 мегабайт.

Comment: Готовый код вы ищите не там, вам на фриланс =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделала вот так:
В **uses** добавить: **System.IOUtils, System.Types;**

**На кнопку код**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Dyn: TStringDynArray;
    Index: array of integer;
    Ish, Rezultat: TStringList;
    i, m, q: integer;
    s: String;
begin
  Dyn := TFile.ReadAllLines('Ishodniy_fayl.txt');
  SetLength(Index, Length(Dyn));
  Ish := TStringList.Create;
  for i := Low(Dyn) to High(Dyn) do
   begin
     s := Copy(Dyn[i], Pos('№', Dyn[i]) + 1, Pos('>', Dyn[i]) - Pos('№', Dyn[i]) - 1);
     q := Ish.IndexOf(s);
     if q = -1 then Index[i] := Ish.Add(s) else Index[i] := q;
   end;
  for i := 0 to Ish.Count - 1 do
   begin
    Rezultat := TStringList.Create;
    for m := Low(Index) to High(Index) do
     if Index[m] = i then Rezultat.Add(Dyn[m]);
    Rezultat.SaveToFile(Format('%s%s.txt', [ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)), Ish.Strings[i]]));
    Rezultat.Free;
   end;
  Ish.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Ну реально восхищаюсь вашим ответом, ведь все так просто и главное работает!!!!!!! Правда на 800 метровых файлах не пробовал но проведу тестирование. Главное что код, хотя бы рабочий...!!! Татьяна ВЫ сделали благое дело!

Comment: @Денис, Я не сильна в delphi, на самом деле тоже учу все постепенно, что получается а что нет. Многие ребята на stackoverflow и до сих пор наставляют и помогают мне в решении моих задач. А мой ответ на ваш вопрос это простой код, который мог сделать любой программист. По поводу файлов в 800 мегабайт то не уверенна я что код сможет обработать их (Очень много строк, при таком задании - все равно забьет память). Но Вы просили рабочий код, я что смогла то и сделала (На сколько хватило моего опыта). Как то так, сама понимаю что бывает не просто, но надеюсь помогла.

Answer (score 3):

Самое первое что приходит в голову - ассоциативный массив списков.
Но первая же проблема в Delphi-7 например такой отсутствует, если у вас более новая верси(2009 и новее) шаги 1 и 2 можно пропустить(используя `TDictonary<sKey:strintg; sValue:TStringList>`).

1) Реализуем способ для хранения пар ключ-значение

```
Type
  tMyObject = class
    Val : string;        //Строка между № и > 
    Item : tStringList   //Список строк у которых одинаковый Val
  end;
```

2a) Можно пойти простым способом и завести обычный список(плохая идея):

```
Var
  Files : Tlist;
```

2б) Или пойти более сложным путём реализовав класс(класс упрощен, и в качестве примера, опущены многие необходимые вещи)

```
Type 
  tFiles = class
  private
    _Items : TList;
    Function _GetList(sKey:string):tMyObject;
  Public
    Property List[Key:string]:tMyObject read _GetList; default;
    Function isItem(Key:string):boolean;        //Реализуете сами, это просто.
    Function AsArray(Id:Integer):tMyObject      // тоже сами - подсказка _Items[Id];
    Function Count : Integer;                   // - подсказка _Items.Count;
  end;
....
Function tFiles._GetList(sKey:string):tMyObject;
Var 
  i:integer;
begin
  // 1* 2* - эту часть можно легко улучшить(соединить).
  if (isList(Key)) then                                       //1*
  Begin
    for i:=0 to _Items.Count do with tMyObject(_Items[i]) do  //2*
    if(val=sKey)
    begin
       result := tMyObject(_Items[i]);
       break;
    end;
  End else
  Begin
    Result:=tMyObject.Create;
    Result.Val := Key;
    Result.Item := tStringList.Create;
  end;
end;
```

3. Считать входной файл в массив строк(заменить на TStringList - MyArray:tStingList)
4. Пройтись по каждой строке

   - а) `pos1 = pos(MyArray[i],'№'); pos2 = pos(MyArray[i],'№',pos1);`
   - б) Добавить нашу строку в наш класс:
     `Str1 := copy(MyArray[i],pos1,pos2-pos1);
     tFiles[Str1].Item.Add(MyArray[i]);`
5. Сохранить в файл все полученные "массивы"

   - a) `for i:=0 to tFiles.count-1 do tFiles.AsArray[i].SaveToFile(IntToStr(i));`
   - б) `for i:=0 to TDictonary.count-1 do tFiles.ToArray[i].Value.SaveToFile(IntToStr(i));`

**P.s. В ответе приведены лишь примеры, это не самый оптимальный способ решения, а только намек как это можно решить**